Linux 5.19.8 has removed genhd.h?
I'm working on a block device driver kernel module. Most tutorials use the genhd.h header file, but when I checked my kernel code (version Linux 5.19.8), I couldn't find that header file. How should I proceed? Where has the content of that header file been moved in the newer versions? Or how can I implement the block device driver kernel module without using that header file?

Apparently genhd.h has been removed; see https://lore.kernel.org/all/9bb3f4c6-4e21-e1d7-b4e1-f65d273cd3f8@nvidia.com/t/
Commit message says:

This patchset removes the <linux/genhd.h> header, which has no clearly
split responsibilities from <linux/blkdev.h> and is included by the
latter

From that I would infer that the workaround is to #include blkdev.h instead.  (Or drop the genhd.h #include entirely if it was redundant.)
